# What gulp-release-tasks exactly does?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I couldn't understand what does the [gulp-release-tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-release-tasks) module exactly. it's written that it's a "scoped release tasks for gulp" : what is that ?! and that it "bumps the versions of your package.json and bower.json" what does it mean? i found it used in a project generated automatically with the [generator-gulp-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-gulp-angular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bower* and *npm* are package managers and `bower.json` and `package.json` are their configuration files (respectively).

You can install and save your project dependencies with commands like `bower install [package] --save` which will add records to your `bower.json` (or `package.json`).

In those configurations files you specify version of your project and repository (you want to keep clean record of what dependencies belong to which versions of your project):

```
"repository": "[your repository]",
"version": "0.0.3",
```

This is where `gulp-release-tasks` comes into play. It allows you to automate process of managing *semantic versioning* ([doc](http://semver.org/)) of those configs. You can run commands such as `gulp bump --minor`   which will bump version (for example) from `v0.0.3` -> `v0.1.0`, commit changes and automatically push to your repository. Or you can perform those operations directly from your gulp tasks.